# Get attribute admin option value if you have option Id or store view value

Tags: custom-options

I'm trying since hours but I'm not able to load the admin option value of a certain attribute. Although I have enough information like option_id and store view value:

```
$attributeId = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute')->getIdByCode('catalog_product','color');
$attribute = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute')->load($attributeId);
$attributeOptions = $attribute ->getSource()->getAllOptions();
```

My attribute (name: color) option table looks like

```
Admin      Default Store View
15            white
20            yellow
22            blue
45            green
```

Following gives me only the option ids:

```
$colorOfProduct = "white";
$attributeId = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute')->getIdByCode('catalog_product','color');
$attribute = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute')->load($attributeId);
$attributeOptions = $attribute ->getSource()->getAllOptions();

foreach ($attributeOptions as $option) {
    if ($option['label'] == $colorOfProduct)
    echo $option['value'];
}
```

I have the Default store view value (i.e. white) and need the assigned Admin value. Unfortunately I don't get it done and appreciate every help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For getting option value for admin

then you can get by below code and Where 0 is admin store id

```
$attributeId = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute')->getIdByCode('catalog_product','color');
 $collection =Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_option_collection')
                ->setPositionOrder('asc')
                ->setAttributeFilter($attributeId)
                ->setStoreFilter(0)
                ->load();
                echo "<pre>";
                print_r($collection->toOptionArray());
                echo "</pre>";
```

You need to just change store

```
 view ids on place of 0;
```

Comment: You pointed me in the right direction. Thank you so much for your help! I'm gonna post my full solution tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

Here my full solution for a certain problem. Perhaps someone can use it.

```
    function getImgColor($productId, $colorOfProduct)
    {
    $optionId = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getAttributeRawValue($productId, 'color', 1);

    $attributeId = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute')->getIdByCode('catalog_product','color');
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_option_collection')
        ->setPositionOrder('asc')
        ->setAttributeFilter($attributeId)
        ->setStoreFilter(0)
        ->load();

    $collection = $collection->toOptionArray();

    foreach ($collection as $option) {
        if ($option['value'] == $optionId) {
            $img = $option["label"];
            break;
        }
    }

    return file_exists(Mage::getBaseDir('media')."/colorall/_thumbs/color/".$img.".png") ? "<img src=\"".Mage::getBaseUrl('media')."colorall/_thumbs/color/".$img.".png\" title=\"".$colorOfProduct."\" />" : Mage::getBaseDir('media')."/colorall/_thumbs/color/".$img.".png";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this more simply in a single call as follows:

Example attribute 'gender' to get custom attribute value for and we are using the magic method getGender() to do the equivalent of getData('gender')

```
$gender = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute')->loadByCode(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, 'gender')->getSource()->getOptionText($product->getGender());
```

Answer (score 0):

set store id before retriving value

```
$attribute->setStoreId(\Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID)->getFrontend()->getValue($product)
```